# Loading (StaticQuery) white screen on Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, gatsby, eslint

I am getting the error reported on this issue: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25920
But the people from Gatsby seems to be too busy to answer so maybe someone else here knows about this problem.

Have in mind that I am not using the `StaticQuery` component at all on my code.

I am getting this exact same issue.

I noticed some other devs before having it: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/6350

I saw that some devs recommend removing the `export` from the `query` variable, so this:

```js
const query = graphql`...`
```

Instead of this:

```js
export const query = graphql`...`
```

But this is not my case. Everything was working good until some hours ago.

I have all of my pages with queries like this:

```
// this is my component
const CollectionProduct = ({ data }) => {...}

// and outside the component is the query
export const query = graphql`
  query($handle: String!) {
    shopifyCollection(handle: { eq: $handle }) {
      products {
        id
        title
        handle
        createdAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

In that component I am using `export` on `const query`, all of my pages are defined the same way and before there were no problems. I already upgrade and downgrade the version of Gatsby and yet the same issue.

My issues comes exactly after I added a `.eslintrc.js` config file to the project; is this an option that my project build fails on the live site due to ESLint?

Locally it works, I can build the project and see it on my `localhost` with no problems. But when I see the live site, it throws that `Loading(StaticQuery)` white screen. And I am not even using `StaticQuery` component anywhere. Only the `useStaticQuery` hook on non page nor templates components.

This is my ESLint config:

```js
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    __PATH_PREFIX__: true,
  },
  'parser': 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    extraFileExtensions: ['.js'],    
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    useJSXTextNode: true,
    include: ['**/*js'],
  },
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true,
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    serviceworker: true,
  },
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:react/recommended', 'semistandard', 'plugin:import/react'],
  plugins: ['react'],
  rules: {
    semi: 'off',
    'strict': 0,
    curly: [1, 'all'],
    'no-console': 'error',
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    camelcase: ['off', {}],
    'react/jsx-uses-vars': 1,
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 1,
    'react/jsx-boolean-value': 2,
    "react/display-name": 'warn',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 1,
    'brace-style': ['error', '1tbs'],
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'never'],
    'linebreak-style': ['error', 'unix'],
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'off',
    'standard/no-callback-literal': [0, []],
    'padding-line-between-statements': [
      'error',
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'return' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'multiline-const' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'multiline-const', next: '*' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'block-like' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'block-like', next: '*' },
    ],
    'react/jsx-curly-brace-presence': [
      'error',
      { props: 'never', children: 'never' },
    ],
  },
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any update on this ? I am having this issue with Gatsby 4.2.0 but I think is something with the cache

Answer (score 1):

Delete cache storage from the browser and reload the page. Or Hard Reload the page and see, This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which happened all of a sudden. Someone on https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/24890 suggested to try to clean your project.

For me deleting both `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` to then regenerate them did the trick!

EDIT: This [seems to have been fixed](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25920#issuecomment-663444727) with gatsby 2.24.11

Comment: I'm using `"gatsby": "^3.7.1"`, doesn't seem to have been fixed 

Answer (score 0):

Updating the cli with`npm i -g gatsby-cli` solved this problem for me

Answer (score 0):

just remove yarn.lock and work is done

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Hitesh Shimpi

Answer (score 0):

none of the above solutions worked for me.

a possible solution that worked for me was to copy and delete the page that was showing the white screen, generate a new build, and then add the same page again for the next build. This seemed to fix the issue for me.

It's unclear why this workaround works, but it's possible that there might be some caching issues with Gatsby or its plugins that are causing the issue. Hopefully, this solution will work for you too.